# How to refactor polymorphic method to keep code DRY

Tags: python, polymorphism

Here is an example of the code I am working with while learning polymorphic behaviour in python.
My question is: Why do I have to declare the very similar function of show_affection twice? Why not check if the caller (the instance calling the method) and if it is Dog, do one thing, if it is a cat do another.

As you can see in the example code below, show_affection is defined in both Cat and Dog classes which inherit from Animal.

Why not declare show_affection in the Animal Class but I am not sure how to check for the caller. like

```
def show_affection(self):

    If caller is the Dog instance:
        print("{0}.barks".format(self.name))
    else:
        print("{0}.wags tail".format(self.name))
```

Here is the what I have

```
class Animal(object):

    def __init__(self, name):

        self.name = name
    def eat(self, food):
        print("{0} eats {1}".format(self.name, food))

class Dog(Animal):


    def fetch(self, thing):
        print("{0} goes after the {1}".format(self.name, thing))
    def show_affection(self):
        print("{0} wags tail".format(self.name))


class Cat(Animal):

    def swatstring(self):
        print("{0} shreds the string".format(self.name))

    def show_affection(self):
        print("{0} purrs".format(self.name))


for a in (Dog('rover'), Cat('fluffy'), Cat('precious'), Dog('Scout')):
    a.show_affection()

a.eat('bananas')
```

Comment: This means the `Animal` class needs to know all of the potential sub-classes, which means it isn't very extensible... I would caution about over applying any of the these principles like DRY. But to answer your question you can test `type(self) == Dog`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an example of "repeating yourself", because `Cat.show_affection()` does something different from `Dog.show_affection()`.  If the two methods were the same, then you could avoid repetition by defining the implementation once in `Animal`.  But since you want to have different behaviors for `Cat` and `Dog`, the correct way to do it is to implement the method in each class.

In general:

- Cat-specific behaviors should be defined in `Cat`.
- Dog-specific behaviors should be defined in `Dog`.
- Behaviors that apply to all animals should be defined in `Animal`.